# why bigInteger doesn't have bit length for -1?

Tags: java, biginteger

why does `BigInteger.bitLength()` print `0` for `-1` in Java:

```java
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(-1).bitLength());
```

there is a comment in the source code for BigInteger that says:

> bitLength not initialized yet

```java
public int bitLength() {
        int n = bitLengthPlusOne - 1;
        if (n == -1) { // bitLength not initialized yet
            int[] m = mag;
            int len = m.length;
            if (len == 0) {
                n = 0; // offset by one to initialize
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "because bitLength not initialized yet" (with the latter part apparently being a quotation) - could you clarify?

Comment: `bitLength()`: "Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this BigInteger, excluding a sign bit" - minimal 2's complement that can represent `-1` is just a one bit long number (only sign, representing the numbers -1 and 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation for the [`BigInteger.bitLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength--) method:

> Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this BigInteger, *excluding* a sign bit. [...]

You need zero "value" bits to represent the value `0`. Basically, you "don't need to do anything" and you have the value `0`. With the sign bit you can switch between `0` and `-1` (as similar to the two's-complement).

When you have the value `1` you need one "value" bit, so `BigInteger.bitLength()` will return `1` for the BigInteger value `1`. Check the following `for` loop and the output it generates:

```
for (int i=-16; i<=16; i++) {
    BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
    System.out.println(x+"| bitlength: "+x.bitLength());    
}
```

The output is:

```
-16| bitlength: 4
-15| bitlength: 4
-14| bitlength: 4
-13| bitlength: 4
-12| bitlength: 4
-11| bitlength: 4
-10| bitlength: 4
-9| bitlength: 4
-8| bitlength: 3
-7| bitlength: 3
-6| bitlength: 3
-5| bitlength: 3
-4| bitlength: 2
-3| bitlength: 2
-2| bitlength: 1
-1| bitlength: 0
0| bitlength: 0  /* 0b */
1| bitlength: 1  /* 0b1 */
2| bitlength: 2
3| bitlength: 2  /* 0b11 */
4| bitlength: 3
5| bitlength: 3
6| bitlength: 3
7| bitlength: 3  /* 0b111 */
8| bitlength: 4
9| bitlength: 4
10| bitlength: 4
11| bitlength: 4
12| bitlength: 4
13| bitlength: 4
14| bitlength: 4
15| bitlength: 4 /* 0b1111 */
16| bitlength: 5
```

Comment: Careful, you typed `#bitCount` but linked `#bitLength`, `#bitCount` won't exclude the sign bit iirc

Answer (score 3):

It returns the minimal [two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (`1`), exluding the sign bit, which makes it 0 in this case. The binary value of -1 is `0xFFFF...`/`0b1111...`, with the one's complement (max - value) becoming `0`, which adds to `1` to become the two's complement (one's complement + 1).

However, the `n` variable from `#bitLength` is not the value of your BigInteger, but the value of the stored bitLength field minus 1 (and `0` means it wasn't calculated yet). So the `BigInteger` with a value of `-1` returning a `0` from `#bitLength` is a coincidence with respect to them using -1 as a sentinal value.

They use this value to denote the field has not been [lazily initialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) yet, and then the `bitLength` field is set to the correct value (0). Keep in mind, `BigInteger` is immutable, so when the bitLength is calculated, it will not ever change for that instance.

Comment: so two's complement in 2 bits is `0b11` and when you convert that back to signed number representation you get `0b00` which takes `0` bits.

Comment: not quite, `0b00` is the one's complement: `max - 0b11 == 0b11 - 0b11 == 0`, but for the two's complement you add 1 to it to get a result of `0b01`. The resulting number is the negation of the original number, and the most significant bit is a sign bit. You have two bits in that system, allowing you the numbers `-2, -1, 0, 1` (`-2` is `0b10`). When this method gives you a `0`, it's returning that because you only need 1 bit to represent -1. `0b0` is 0, and `0b1` is -1. Thus, excluding a sign bit, you need 0 bits to represent it.

Comment: I spent the last half hour deciphering what you have written. but thanks to @Progman & your explanation I think I get it now.                                                                                                                     `-1` is `0b11`(signed number) --(negate bits)--> `0b00`(one's complement) --(+1)--> `0b01`(two's complement) --(`BigInteger doesn't count 0s from left`)--> `0b1` --(`exclude sign bit from bitLength`)--> `0b` ----> we are left with 0 bits.